# Do content observer run in the background

Tags: android

I was wondering, if I coded a content observer in an Activity would it be running in the background even if the activity is not created or started. Do I have to code it on a service for it to run in the background?

Answer (score 2):

- Short answer: No, it won't run if your `Activity` is not created. If you want your activity to be notified via *Observer* pattern, you can use subscribe in your `onResume`, `onCreate`, and unsubscribe  in your `onPause` or `onDestroy`. My choice would be to use `onResume` and `onPause`, This way, your `Activity` won't be notified if it's not visible. You can check `Activity` lifecycles [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).
- If you want a content observer, that runs in the background, you have to implement your own [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). [More about services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).